# Refresh the data in all view controllers in SplitView based iPad app

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

What are the best practices to connect master tableView to a detail view(a tabBarViewController)?

Also in my case when ever i select a row all the viewControllers inside the tabar should refresh/reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delegate tableView methods in your tabBarViewController. Write `<UITableViewDelegate>` in your interface declaration.